# DirectShowLib - Save video with overlay text

Tags: c#, directshow

How to save the graph obtained after processing at avi file. Managed to get pictures with the overlay's text. I know that there is a method SetOutputFileName(), but how to use it here?

```
private Bitmap bitmapOverlay;
private IFilterGraph2 m_FilterGraph;


 void GO()
        {

        SetupGraph("C:\\Export.avi");
        SetupBitmap();

        IMediaControl mediaCtrl = m_FilterGraph as IMediaControl;
        int hr = mediaCtrl.Run();
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

        }
```

```
 private void SetupGraph(string FileName)
                {
                    int hr;

                IBaseFilter ibfRenderer = null;
                ISampleGrabber sampGrabber = null;
                IBaseFilter capFilter = null;
                IPin iPinInFilter = null;
                IPin iPinOutFilter = null;
                IPin iPinInDest = null;

                // Get the graphbuilder object
                m_FilterGraph = new FilterGraph() as IFilterGraph2;

                    // Get the SampleGrabber interface
                 sampGrabber = new SampleGrabber() as ISampleGrabber;

                    // Add the video source
                 hr = m_FilterGraph.AddSourceFilter(FileName, "Ds.NET FileFilter", out capFilter);
                 DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

                    // Hopefully this will be the video pin
                 IPin iPinOutSource = DsFindPin.ByDirection(capFilter, PinDirection.Output, 0);

                 IBaseFilter baseGrabFlt = sampGrabber as IBaseFilter;
                 ConfigureSampleGrabber(sampGrabber);

                 iPinInFilter = DsFindPin.ByDirection(baseGrabFlt, PinDirection.Input, 0);
                 iPinOutFilter = DsFindPin.ByDirection(baseGrabFlt, PinDirection.Output, 0);

                    // Add the frame grabber to the graph
                 hr = m_FilterGraph.AddFilter( baseGrabFlt, "Ds.NET Grabber" );
                 DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

                 hr = m_FilterGraph.Connect(iPinOutSource, iPinInFilter);
                 DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

                    // Get the default video renderer
                 ibfRenderer = (IBaseFilter) new VideoRendererDefault();

                    // Add it to the graph
                 hr = m_FilterGraph.AddFilter( ibfRenderer, "Ds.NET VideoRendererDefault" );
                 DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );
                 iPinInDest = DsFindPin.ByDirection(ibfRenderer, PinDirection.Input, 0);

                    // Connect the graph.  Many other filters automatically get added here
                 hr = m_FilterGraph.Connect(iPinOutFilter, iPinInDest);
                 DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

                 SaveSizeInfo(sampGrabber);

            }
```

Process video - draw on each frame text.
cc.Save ("C: \\ Test \\ img" + m_Count + ".jpg") - so get shots with superimposed text.
How to make the processed video file saved in avi file?

```
int ISampleGrabberCB.BufferCB( double SampleTime, IntPtr pBuffer, int BufferLen )
            {
            Graphics g;
            String s;
            float sLeft;
            float sTop;
            SizeF d;

            g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapOverlay);
            g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; 

            // Prepare to put the specified string on the image
            g.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Blue, 0, 0, m_videoWidth - 1, m_videoHeight - 1);
            g.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Blue, 1, 1, m_videoWidth - 3, m_videoHeight - 3);

            d = g.MeasureString(m_String, fontOverlay);

            sLeft = (m_videoWidth - d.Width) / 2;
            sTop = (m_videoHeight - d.Height ) / 2;

            g.DrawString(m_String, fontOverlay, System.Drawing.Brushes.Red, 
                sLeft, sTop, System.Drawing.StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            g.Dispose();


            Bitmap v;
            v = new Bitmap(m_videoWidth, m_videoHeight, m_stride,
                PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb, pBuffer);

            v.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
            g = Graphics.FromImage(v);
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            // draw the overlay bitmap over the video's bitmap
            g.DrawImage(bitmapOverlay, 0, 0, bitmapOverlay.Width, bitmapOverlay.Height);

        Bitmap cc = new Bitmap(v);
            cc.Save("C:\\Test\\img" + m_Count + ".jpg");

        g.Dispose();
        v.Dispose();
        m_Count++;
        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Please indent your code so it's easier to read. Also tag it with the relevant language to get syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Typically it should look like:

```
[File reader] -> [AVI Demuxer] -> (video pin) -> [Video decoder] -> [Sample grabber] -> [Video encoder] -> [AVI Muxer] -> [File writer]
                      |->                                             (audio pin)                             ->|
```

AVI file is a media container so you need to demultiplex it to separate streams and at the end to multiplex (modified) streams back to AVI container. When you got video stream it (typically) contains encoded video. So to modify it you need to decode it and then after modification encode it back to the same format. You don't need to do anything about audio stream, just direct it from demuxer straight to muxer. [File writer] filter allows you to specify output file name.

I don't know what is "Ds.NET FileFilter" and how it can demux and then decode the video, but seems it can because you can see your modified picture. AVI Muxer is a standard MS filter, I just don't remember its name. You need to choose a video encoder. I'd recommend first to build a simple graph in GraphEditor that doesn't modify the picture but just read->demux->decod->encode->mux->write to verify you have everything you need and they work fine. Just try to play resulting AVI file.